# batchUpdate method throws errors while updating Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I am trying to create a presentation and update it on Google Apps Scripts. The creation is successful. However when I try to update the title or add a new shape or text it throws errors.
Is there any other update method? Also is it possible to update the presentation after modifying the texts without updating all of the presentation? I don't want to create an add-on I just want to be able to update the slides with executing the scripts.

---

**Code:**

```js
function createAndUpdatePresentation() {
    const createdPresentation = Slides.Presentations.create({"title": "MyNewPresentation"});
    const link = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${createdPresentation.presentationId}/edit`;
    Logger.log(`Created presentation is on: ${link}`);

    const request = {
      requests: [
        {
          updateTitle: {
            title: 'My Updated Presentation'
          }
        }
      ]
    };

    const updatedPresentation = 
      Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(request, createdPresentation.presentationId);

    const updatedLink = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${updatedPresentation.presentationId}/edit`;
    Logger.log(`Updated presentation is on: ${updatedLink}`);
}
```

**Error:** `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to slides.presentations.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "updateTitle" at 'requests[0]': Cannot find field.`

Comment: In the first Code case there is no `updateTitle` for a `batchUpdate` request.  And why when you are creating a new presentation.  Simple set the title in the presentation.  In the second Code case `createdPresentation` is a response.  You can't use it as a request.

Comment: @TheWizEd just removed second case. For first case I mean to update other fields but wanted to show with title. Whenever I try createLine or insert something methods they are throwing errors also. Just want to verify how I can update and see the result on slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to edit a new presentation, one using SlidesApp and the second using Slides API.

```
function newPresentation1() {
  try {
    let presentation = Slides.Presentations.create({'title': 'MyNewPresentation'});
    presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentation.presentationId);
    let slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
    let element = slide.getPageElements()[0];
    element.asShape().getText().setText("Hello")
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

function newPresentation2() {
  try {
    let presentation = Slides.Presentations.create({'title': 'MyNewPresentation'});
    let pageElement = presentation.slides[0].pageElements[0].objectId;
    let request = { insertText: { objectId: pageElement,
                                  text: "Good bye" }
                  };
    Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate( { requests: [ request ] }, presentation.presentationId );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Reference

- [SlidesApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app)
- [Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest)